# Google Cloud Platform networking: Resolve VM hostname to its assigned internal IP even when not running?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

> Is there any way in the GCP, to allow VM hostnames to be resolved to their IPs even when the VMs are stopped?

Listing VMs in a project reveals their assigned internal IP addresses even when the VMs are stopped. This means that, as long as the VMs aren't re-created, their internal IPs are statically assigned.

However, when our VMs are stopped, the DNS resolution stops working:

```
ping: my-vm: Name or service not known
```

even though the IP is kept assigned to it, according to `gcloud compute instances list`.

I've tried reserving the VM's current internal IP:

```
gcloud compute addresses create my-vm --addresses 10.123.0.123 --region europe-west1 --subnet default
```

However, the address name `my-vm` above is not related to the VM name `my-vm` and the reservation has no effect (except for making the IP unavailable for automatic assignment in case of VM re-creation).

---

> But why?

Some fault-tolerant software will have a configuration for connecting to multiple machines for redundancy, and if at least one of the connections could be established, the software will run fine. But if the hostname cannot be resolved, this software would not start at all, forcing us to hard-code the DNS in `/etc/hosts` (which doesn't scale well to a cluster of two dozen VMs) or to use IP addresses (which gets hairy after a while). Specific example here is `freeDiameter`.

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses the IP ICMP protocol. This requires that the target is running and responding to network requests.

Google Compute Engine VMs use DHCP for private IP addresses. DHCP is integrated with (communicates with) Google DNS. DHCP informs DNS about running network services (VM IP address and hostname). If the VM is shutdown, this link does not exist. DHCP/DNS information is updated/replaced/deleted hourly.

You can set up Google Cloud DNS private zones, create entries for your VPC resources and resolve private IP addresses and hostnames that persist.

Comment: Your response about ping is completely besides the point. *Obviously*, to get a reply, the host needs to be running. What I hope to get when the host is down, is for DNS resolution to work, and then for ICMP packets to get dropped.

Comment: The response about hourly update/delete of DHCP/DNS information cannot possibly be correct either, as the DNS<->IP association is destroyed within less than 5 seconds after the full stop of a VM. Also, the DHCP lease is always between 20 and 30 minutes for me. So this *cannot* be an explanation for observed behavior.

Comment: My hypothesis is that the internal virtualization subsystem [de]provisions the hostname<->IP association to the internal DNS as VMs pop in and out of existence as part of VM start/stop. My point is, there is more than simple DHCP going on here, and I was hoping to somehow have this association remain permanent (until deletion of VM at least) without manual DNS setup; because the information *is* permanent in the virtualization subsystem (as seen in `gcloud` command output).

Comment: While I have issues with your first two paragraphs in the answer, I'll take home the recommendation to simply configure my own Private Zone DNS in the GCP. If that works out well I'll accept the answer.

Comment: From what I can see, having a private DNS Zone means that I have to manually manage the IP assignment to hostnames which isn't very helpful: I want this assignment to be automatic, in the sense that whatever internal IP the hostname 'vm1' is assigned by the *Internal DNS* (the metadata server), that this hostname then resolves to that IP even when the VM is stopped.

Comment: Private IP addresses are not static as they are managed by DHCP. When an instance boots up it uses DHCP to request a Private IP address. Like most DHCP servers, your instance will get the same IP address usually, but this is not guaranteed. You can assign static private IP addresses if you want. In that case, you must manage the DNS entries yourself.